# How to get value of variable through BeautifulSoup with soup.select_one()?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can you get the value of the variable `ue_mid` if you were trying to scrape a web page using BeautifulSoup and also using this function: `soup.select_one()`?

This is how the list of variables on the source code looks like:

```
var ue_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    ue_mid = 'ValueToGet',
    ue_navtiming = 1;
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: it is JavaScript - you can get it as single string and later use string's functions (or regex) to extract it from string. `select_one()` is useless here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is JavaScript. You can use `select_one()` only to get text from tag `<script>` and later you have to use string's functions (or regex) to extract it from string.

```
html = '''<script>
var ue_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    ue_mid = 'ValueToGet',
    ue_navtiming = 1;
</script>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
text = soup.select_one('script').get_text()

text = text.split("ue_mid = '")[1]
text = text.split("',")[0]
print(text)

# ValueToGet
```